# Database design & 3rd party integrations

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

We're building an application where eCommerce owners can connect their store from different platforms (e.g. Shopify, Magento, Woocommerce). We do this in order to import data from these various platforms.

So we have a `Stores` table. In there we have data that are common to all platforms and some data that are specific to the platforms.

I'm not sure what to do here. Should we create specific tables that contain platform-specific information or we create columns to store certain information but that will be empty for the stores from the other platforms?

What would be the pros and cons? Knowing that we would then need to create tables for all new platforms that we integrate with if we go for option 2.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said which specific RDBMS you're using, but with PostgreSQL you have the option of foreign data wrappers. These let you federate data from other sources and APIs into your application database and read and write foreign tables just like you do the internal tables (assuming the external APIs allow you to modify data). With this approach, you just need to make sure that your `stores` are properly associated with their respective entries in the foreign tables. Developing FDWs is relatively easy with [Multicorn](http://multicorn.org/).

If that's not an option: using columns is efficient to query since the information is right there in your store record. However, it could get unwieldy depending on how much of it there is, and if you could have a tenant with multiple presences on one of those external platforms -- weirder things *have* happened -- you're in for some trouble. And the relational form makes adding and changing support for the external platforms easier since you don't have to lock the entire tenants table to add or remove columns.

The simpler approach may be all you need to start out with, but it'd probably be smart to plan for tables in the end.